# Acess HTML input from both client and server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have an input textbox and I need to access it from both JavaScript and server side C#. 
If I insert runat="server", the control will be accessible only from the server.

```
<input id="txtSearch" /> // Accessible only from JavaScript
<input id="txtSearch" runat="server"/> // Accessible only from C#
```

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: You can access both.... Look at the generated source code and see why you can not select the element by its id. ;)

Comment: @epascarello ok but my code don't see it.

Comment: Did you look at the html and see why? What is the id after you set the runat?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad read the question before commenting.

Comment: @Ado i have read the question, it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: @EhsanSajjad you didn't understand but you marked as duplicate.  Ok, I got it.

Comment: @Ado i voted to close as the question is not clear, duplicate is marked by other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `runat="server"`, .net web form will do some modifications to your controls, in this case your `input`'s ID will no long is txtSearch anymore, that would be something like "form_1abcasd_txtSearch". You could fix the issue by `ClientIdMode="Static"` to get rid of that.

If you are using jQuery, you could use `$("input[id$='txtSearch']")` to access the element as well.

Comment: The solution about jQuery worked! Which one would be best ClientIdMode="Static" and $("input[id$='txtSearch']")?

Comment: I recommend `ClientIdMode` unless you can ensure you won't have duplicated ID tails, like `txtSearch` and `atxtSearch`

Comment: @Ado you may also want to read more: http://blog.zay-dev.com/net-web-form-implementation-strategy-1-the-over-postback/